# Unexpected use of 'event' no-restricted-globals when use a keyboard input event

Tags: reactjs, kendo-grid

I am using onKeyPress event to allow number and dash character from keyboard when add text in a Gid column.

`<GridColumn field="phoneNumber" title="Phone Number" editor="text" width="400" onKeyPress={event => this.isAllowKey(event)} />`

```
isAllowKey(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    console.log(charCode);
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode != 45 && charCode > 31
        && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

But I had issue **Unexpected use of 'event'  no-restricted-globals** when I use event from DOM in event.keyCode.

I am using GridColumn component of Kendo React.

Anyone can give me a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The argument - the event - is named `evt`. In the second part of the conditional you're not using it, but instead using the (not recommended) `window.event`.

```
: event.keyCode;
```

should be

```
: evt.keyCode;
```

Or, even better - name the *argument* `event` and use that everywhere instead, so that it shadows `window.event` and eliminates the possibility of these sorts of problems.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I tried it and it resolve problem. But onKeyPress cannot active in the interface of GridColumnProps.

Comment: That's a completely separate issue from what your original question is asking about...